# Best way to estimate the probabilities of a random variable

Tags: time-series, probability, maximum-likelihood, estimators

I have some confusion about estimating the probability of a particular value of a random variable. For simplicity, consider the case of a coin and the random variable being $X = \{H,T\}$, where $T$ is drawing a tail and $H$ a head.

I know that you can estimate the probability of drawing a tail experimentally by counting the number of tails, $N_T$, after an infinite number of throws, $N$:

$$p_{T} = \lim_{N \to  \infty} \frac{N_T}{N}.$$

In practice, however you have something like this, when plotting $p_T (N)$:[image]

That is, it converges slowly and you never have the real value.

**My question:** What is the best way to estimate $p_T$, $\bar{p}_T$, and a measure of the uncertainty of the estimation $\varepsilon_{\bar{p}_T}$?

- **Approach 1: Maximum likelihood**
  I have read somewhere that the most simple estimate, that is, 
  $$\bar{p}_{T}^I = \frac{N_T}{N},$$
  is also the most probable one according to our data (I'm not 100% sure I understand this argument). However, how can I estimate its uncertainty? Something like the standard deviation of the mean?
  $$\varepsilon_{\bar{p}_T} = \frac{\sigma_T}{\sqrt{N}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{i=1}^N \left( X_i^T - \bar{p}_{T}^I \right)^2 } $$
  where $X_i^T=1$ if we have a tail in throw $i$?
- **Approach 2: Moving average after a transient number of points**
  What I feel makes more sense to me looking at the previous plot is instead of taking the last value as our estimate, taking a moving average after some $\alpha$ points, in the previous plot it could be for example $\alpha = 10000$:
  $$\bar{p}_T^{II} = \frac{1}{N-\alpha+1} \sum_{t=\alpha}^N \frac{N_T^t}{t},$$
  where $N_T^t$ is the number of tails at step $t$.
  In this way you are filtering over the fluctuations you can see in the picture and you can estimate the error of $\bar{p}_T^{II}$ as the standard deviation of the moving average. I have plotted this measure and its error in the horizontal lines, and I think it does look quite good. With this method you would avoid that you take as the average the value of a fluctuating peak for example.
  However, I can see with this method you are giving more importance to older draws than recent draws, as the draw from time $t=\alpha$ appears $N-\alpha+1$ times in the expression but the draw from time $t=N$ appears only once, which does not make much sense. For example, if you draw only one event at time $t=\alpha$, you would get $\frac{1}{N-\alpha +1}\sum_{t=\alpha}^N \frac{1}{t}$ which is greater than drawing one event at time $t=N$, $\frac{1}{N-\alpha +1} \frac{1}{N}$.

Can you provide some discussion about which is the best method to use and how to solve the apparent paradox when using the moving average (it seems to avoid fluctuations but to give more importance to older events)?

Comment: We know that the MLE in this case is unbiased as well as asymptotically efficient, which means that it has the lowest variability among consistent estimators. The moving average estimate appears to average a large number of estimates, providing equal weight to prior estimates regardless of the number of data points contributing. You need to repeat your simulation a large number of times to assess the variability of each estimator at time $N$ across a large number of simulations, each with $N$ trials. The standard error of the moving average is being calculated incorrectly.

Comment: Your approach (2) is an illusion, because it is not using the right hand side of the plot--by using only the more recent values, it is focusing on the *left* side of the plot.

Comment: @jsk Why the standard error of the moving average is being calculated incorrectly?

Comment: @whuber I don't understand why do you say it focuses on the left side of the plot because it only uses some number $N-\alpha +1$ recent values. The more recent values are on the right. However, I understand the values more on the left that contribute (that is, after $\alpha$), contribute more to the moving average than the values on the right. I don't know if you meant that.

Comment: @Puco4 Because we know the MLE is efficient, we know that no other estimator can have lower variability,. So if (2) has lower variability, it means you are doing something wrong.

Comment: On the right are *averages* of *all* the values, not just the more recent values.  On the left are *averages* of *more recent values,* which is precisely what you are using.  You appear to be reading your plot in reverse!

Comment: @whuber But the thing is with the moving average I do an average of the values of this plot, thus, the values on the left because they appear also in the right, they are counted more times. So yeah, I guess is what you were saying!